# Regex for matching a pair of double pipes with differing inner content

Tags: regex

How do I match a pair of double pipes (i.e. `|| text ||`), while checking the content between the pipes for a singular pipe?

So, `|| text ||` matches `" text "`, while `|| spoiler2|spoiler||` matches `" spoiler2|spoiler"`.

I've tried `\|\|([^\|]+)\|\|`, but that only matches the content without any further pipes between the two pipes.

Comment: Try just `\|\|(.*?)\|\|`

Comment: You could try `\|\|(.*?)\|\|`. This will match anything between a pair of two pipes, but non-greedy (the `?` after the `*`), so as few characters as possible.

Comment: That works perfectly. I never thought of non-greedy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why was my post downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead to ignore a pattern:

```
\|\|((?!\|\|).+)\|\|
```

The `(?!\|\|)` means to not match a `||` string.

Comment: This is a wrong pattern that will match all chars from `||` (not followed with `||`) till the last occurrence of `||`.